# android - replace ViewPager with MapFragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment

I am building one activity that has three fragments, using `ViewPager` and Tabs.
1 - list of locations  ---> click should replace to map fragment
2 - list favorite locations
3 - map

my problem is that when I click on location from the list, `ViewPager` and Tabs does not replaced.

i have tried `pager.setVisibility(View.GONE)` and the `MapFragment` loads ok, but than when click Back - App stops

i would appreciate help about it,

thank you ALL!

this is the onCreate section of code :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

if (savedInstanceState == null) {

            View containerMap = findViewById(R.id.container_map);                               

            fragAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());                     
            pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPager);                                   
            pager.setAdapter(fragAdapter);                                                      
            pager.setCurrentItem(1);                                                            
            PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putBoolean(getResources().getString(R.string.is_search_fragment), true).apply();

            TabLayout tabs = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);                               
            tabs.setupWithViewPager(pager);                                                     
            tabs.setSelectedTabIndicatorColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));    
            tabs.setTabTextColors(Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE);                                    
            tabs.setOnTabSelectedListener(this);                                                

            if (containerMap != null) {
                isTablet = true;
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()                                  
                        .replace(R.id.container_map, new MapFragment(), MapFragment.TAG)
                        .commit();
            } else {
                isTablet = false;                                                               
            }
        }
```

this is the code section relevant at MainActivity :

```
@Override
    public void onLocationSelected(LocationClass location) {
        if (isTablet) {                                         
            ((MapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MapFragment.TAG)).showLocationSelected(location);
        } else {                                                
            MapFragment fragment = new MapFragment();                   
            Bundle b = new Bundle();                                    
            b.putSerializable(MAP_KEY, location);                       
            fragment.setArguments(b);                                   
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container_list, fragment, MapFragment.TAG)
                    .addToBackStack(MapFragment.TAG).commit();          
            pager.setVisibility(View.GONE);  

        }
    }
```

Comment: Please add a code snippet of what you have attempted so far.

Comment: added, sorry about it... my first question ever :)

Comment: It's OK, people on this community are there to help you.